# How to get Code Style like Eclipse on Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am a student and I am developing android apps since 6 months and I was doing it on Eclipse which was include in ADT bundle. but last week I downloaded Android Studio because some of my friends recommended it to me but for me it is like a powerful machine that I can't use.
I am facing problems like-
->When I use to click tab in Eclipse it use to take me out of the parenthesis or braces but in Android Studio when I press Tab key it inserts 6 spaces inside the brackets.
->I am facing several code completion problems because in Eclipse it was working like charm it use to also add the arguments which method was accepting but in android studio it only gives out the method.

[**Click here for Image I don't have enough reputation on stack overflow to upload image**](http://postimg.org/image/4k1e2miel/)

Like in the image here 
in eclipse it was like

```
Log.d(tag, msg);
```

but in Android Studio it is like

```
Log.d();
```

->And the problem not only ends here suppose I want to add any thing like "ArrayList" it is too problematic in Android Studio. like described in image when I do it in eclipse it works like charm but in Android Studio it don't comes out.
[**Click here for Image I don't have enough reputation on stack overflow to upload image**](http://postimg.org/image/rzjb7z25p/)

I only want the coding style like eclipse because it would be too hard for me to work on Android Studio without eclipse coding style.
I tried tweaking with some Android Studio preferences but it didn't help be out.
I want it exact like it is in eclipse.

Thank YOU.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to this setting and configure yourself.

```
Preferences > Keymap > Code > Completion > Basic/SmartType:
```

Comment: SIr, I had cone it but now also it is problematic.

Comment: OK... then either you have to switch back to eclipse or start learning the shortcuts of android studio